# Using angular 1.5 angular.js:Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an Angular 1.2 project, and I have a controller which I want to replace using `Component`. This new component is open from uibModal and it contains another directive.
Before changing it to a component, everthing was fine, but after I changed it I get an error: `Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider`

First component:

```
$ctrl.openImportModal = function () {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'forecastDataNew/modals/importStaffingPlanJobModal/importStaffingPlanJobModal.tpl.html',
        component: 'importStaffingPlanJobModalCtrl',
        windowTopClass: 'import-forecast-data-modal',
        size: 'sm',
        backdrop: 'static'
    });
    ...
```

Second component (which throws the error when I change a component to a controller):

```
angular.module('nice.saas.wfm.importStaffingJob')
    .component('importStaffingPlanJobModalCtrl', {
        templateUrl: 'forecastDataNew/importStaffingPlanJobs.tpl.html',
        bindings: { },
        controller: function($q, $scope, $log, $uibModalInstance, Utils, ForecastDataService) {
            'use strict';
            $scope.filePicked = false;
            $scope.file = { };
            $scope.isClicked = true;
            $scope.uploadCsvAndSave = function(file) {
```

This component includes its HTML directive — if I remove that directive, no error occurs.

Comment: Pass dependecies for that provider in module definition.

Comment: what do you mean? which dependecies?

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('nice.saas.wfm.importStaffingJob',['firebase', 'ui.bootstrap'])
```

Try with this module definition.